# Delta Table Merge Operation logs Output is not correct number of updated records?

Tags: merge, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am performing merge operation on my delta table in spark. I have existing delta table , it already has some records. Now I created another dataframe of csv file, and added one new record and updated one records in that. Please check below snip.

(df_source) is the updated table(temp view)

Now after performing merge operation. The logs generated here are not correct in updated records it shows 3 records updated i have updated only one record. for inserted it shows correctly i have issue with update why it is updating all the records.

Can you please help me to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

delta table
[image: delta table]

UpdatedSourceFile
[image: UpdatedSourceFile]

MergeStatment
[image: MergeStatment]

Comment: Hi @VaibhavB, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your **Merge statement**, you are `updating the records if IDs in both tables are same`. You are getting correct output as, **everytime merge statement found the same id in target table as source table since it is updating that record and because of this, you are getting 3 records updated**.

As per official documentation, *such an update action is considered ambiguous by the SQL semantics of merge since it is not apparent which source record should be utilized to update the matched destination row*.

For your reference, kindly find the below documentation link: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into**